# caption for div - slide in from bottom - slide out to bottom

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I have something like the following :

```
<div class="one-third">
    <div class="inside">
        <h4><strong>How much can you save?</strong></h4>
        <p>testing</p>
        <p>testing</p>
        <p>testing</p>
        <p>testing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">caption here</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to slide in a caption (the div caption) from the bottom that rests on the bottom during hover and slide out the bottom when not hovered. I've looked at a few sources from here and there but can't seem to get it right. It's also important that the main container (one-third) in this case does not resize; the caption should be within it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why you not using javascript? Using jQuery, a javascript framework, will make your task easier.

Comment: Wanna set up a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: *Bottom* of what? Bottom of page; below the `.inside` DIV? When you say "slide in", what kind of animation specifically?

Comment: JQuery IS what I am talking about... I am looking to slide the caption div from below the inside div into it.  I wish there was an easier way to explain it.  Picture the caption div as invisible an then appearing at the bottom of the inside div yet is slides up into place.... similar to something rising from the ground where the bottom of the inside div is the ground.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MPn84/3/)** — Something like this?

Uses CSS3 `transition-duration` ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)) to create the animation.

*Update:*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MPn84/4/)** — So you're looking for the toaster effect?

*Update 2:*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MPn84/5/)** — Animated using jQuery `.animate()` instead.

Comment: No, this is not what I meant... hopefully the comment I posted above explains what I am looking for a little better.

Comment: Given your example the red caption, rather than appear below the inside div would rise from invisible to visible from the bottom of it and rest at the bottom (over top of the 4th grey line). As if if were rising from the ground (bottom of the black box).  Also, I want to use JQuery so this is cross browser (not css3 transitions).

Comment: Updated my answer with "toaster" example.

Comment: That ends up looking right other than there is no transition on my end - it doesn't roll up into place or roll down out of place... like I said, I don't want to use css3 transitions for that reason, but rather JQuery...

Comment: Your wish is my command. Answer updated with jQuery `.animate()` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with.  It covers everything I needed... the toast shows in the bottom upon rollover, the entire div is a link when rolled over, and you can also include links within as well.  The 'animation' only works for FF, but I did this on purpose as my div uses rounded corners... the toast for whatever reason doesn't follow the overflow:hidden so its corners aren't rounded.

```
        <div class="one-third">
            <div class="inside">
                <a href="#"></a>
                <h4><strong>How much can you save?</strong></h4>
                <p>testing</p>
                <p>testing</p>
                <p><a class="link" href="#">testing</a></p>
                <p>testing</p>
                <span class="toast">Learn more about one</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
.one-third{
border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
margin:0 9px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
background:#ffffff;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
cursor: pointer;

}

.one-third:hover{ 
background: #eeeeee;
}

.one-third .inside{
padding:10px;
}

.one-third a{ /*entire div link*/
position:absolute; 
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left: 0;
/* edit: added z-index */
z-index: 1;
}

.one-third a.link { /*links on top of box*/
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}

.one-third .inside .toast {
background: rgb(71, 71, 71); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
bottom: -30px;
line-height:30px;
color: #fff;
font-size:14px;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.1s linear 0s; /*no moz, webkit, or o because radius is needed and won't scroll right*/    
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.one-third:hover .toast {
bottom: 0;
}
```